# Jquery - How to add conditions on $.When

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On a page having two ajax call inside the $.when method. I wanted to make a thrid ajax call based on page-level variable values.

```
$.when(
     $.ajax({...}),
     $.ajax({...}),
.done(function (a, b) {
     ........
});
```

Something like this?

```
$.when(
     $.ajax({...}),
     if(typeof myvalue != "undefined"){ // condition here ?
       $.ajax({...}),
     }
.done(function (a, b) {
     ........
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional expression:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({...}),
    typeof myvalue != "undefined" ? $.ajax({...}) : null
).done(...)
```